# Let $p, q \in \mathbb{R}$ with $p-q>1$. There is such an integer $n$ such that $q<n<p$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, solution-verification

This is what I have thus far, can anyone check if I am on the right track? Also can anyone guide me where to go from here? I am lost as to what to do next.

We will prove this by contradiction. That is, we will assume $q>n>p$ and show a contradiction. We will let $A=\{q,p \in \mathbb{R}: p-q>1\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, we then claim $p$ is an upper bound for $A$. We will assume $u \in A$ and prove $u<p$. We know $p-u>1$ which is equivalent to $p>u$. We can then write this as $u<p$, and since $u<p$, this tells us that $p$ is an upper bound of $A$. We then claim $q$ is an upper bound for $A$. We will assume $v \in A$ and prove $v>p$. We know $v-q>1$ which is equivalent to $v>q$. Since $v>q$, this tells us that $q$ is a lower bound of $A$. We then know $p=sup(A)$ and $q=inf(A)$.

Comment: not following.  The negation of "there is an integer $n$ such that $q<n<p$" is "there is no integer $n$ such that $q<n<p$".  Clearly $p-q>1\implies p>q$ so we know that $q>n>p$ is not possible.

Comment: @MarkBennet In the question they are, but in the proof, I wasn't sure.

Comment: You are supposed to be proving the existence of $n$ and $n$ is supposed to be an integer. I don't see where you are working with integers, but I would go for the greatest integer less than $q$ to start - that's not the one which is going to be $n$ obviously, but it is one you can get a handle on.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to formulate what you're trying to say.

We will prove this by contradiction. Assume there is no integer such that $q < n < p$, and $p - q > 1$. For every integer $n$, we have $n \leq q < p$ or $q <p \leq n$. Examine the set $N = \{n \in \mathbb{Z} : n \geq p\}$. There is a smallest number in this set, call it $m$. We have $m$ satisfies $q < p \leq m$. We also have that $m-1$ is an integer. Since $m-1 < m$, we must have that $m-1 < p$ by minimality. By assumption, if $m-1 < p$ it must also satisfy $m-1 \leq q$. Putting things together, we have $m-1 \leq q < p \leq m$. Now $p-q \leq m - (m-1) = 1$ and this is a contradiction.